# how to retrieve SHA of the next commit in gitlab?

Tags: c#, git, gitlab, commit

I need to show the lastest commit sha as part of the app version , and then commit it . if I get the last sha and save it and then did commit it that mean there is another commit sha ... , So it's like i need to get the sha of the next commit . I'm coding in c# and this is what I tried :

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "git",
                Arguments = "rev-parse --short HEAD",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo })
            {
                
                process.Start();
                string commit= process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                process.WaitForExit();
                Trace.WriteLine(commit);
```

it didn't work .and I don't know if the bash file in the hooks folder will work on windows or no (prepare-commit-msg.sample).

Comment: Are you asking how to get the SHA of a commit that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: When you need to embed the commit hash, you get it during the build/packaging time but don't commit it (sometimes using a tool like GitVersion or Nerdbank.GitVersioning).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what problem you're trying to solve here, but if your goal is to be able to identify deployed code to a specific commit you can use sourcelink libraries, such as this one for gitlab https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SourceLink.GitLab

Answer (score 1):

Checkout is not deploy. Look up `git archive` and the `export-subst` attribute: you can have the exported commit id substituted into the archive. Here's some examples of what you can do with it from [the Pro Git book, free online](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes):

> When exporting files for deployment you can apply git log’s formatting
> and keyword-expansion processing to selected portions of files marked
> with the export-subst attribute.
>
> For instance, if you want to include a file named `LAST_COMMIT` in your
> project, and have metadata about the last commit automatically
> injected into it when git archive runs, you can for example set up
> your `.gitattributes` and `LAST_COMMIT` files like this:
>
> ```
> LAST_COMMIT export-subst
> ```
>
> ```
> $ echo 'Last commit date: $Format:%cd by %aN$' > LAST_COMMIT 
> $ git add LAST_COMMIT .gitattributes 
> $ git commit -am 'adding LAST_COMMIT file for archives'
> ```
>
> When you run git `archive`, the contents of the archived file will look
> like this:
>
> ```
> $ git archive HEAD | tar xCf ../deployment-testing - 
> $ cat ../deployment-testing/LAST_COMMIT
> Last commit date: Tue Apr 21 08:38:48 2009 -0700 by Scott Chacon
> ```
>
> The substitutions can include for example the commit message and any
> git notes, and git log can do simple word wrapping:
>
> ```
> $ echo '$Format:Last commit: %h by %aN at %cd%n%+w(76,6,9)%B$' > LAST_COMMIT
> $ git commit -am 'export-subst uses git log'\''s custom formatter
>
> git archive uses git log'\''s `pretty=format:` processor
> directly, and strips the surrounding `$Format:` and `$`
> markup from the output. '
> $ git archive @ | tar xfO - LAST_COMMIT
> Last commit: 312ccc8 by Jim Hill at Fri May 8 09:14:04 2015 -0700
>        export-subst uses git log's custom formatter
>
>          git archive uses git log's `pretty=format:` processor directly, and
>          strips the surrounding `$Format:` and `$` markup from the output.
> ```
>
> The resulting archive is suitable for deployment work, but like any
> exported archive it isn’t suitable for further development work.